# How to prevent git svn rebase to create empty directories

Tags: directory, git-svn

In short the problem is, when I run git svn rebase, I got a bunch of "creating empty directory: ..."

At the svn side, in trunk, there's a directory named TOD(Trunk Only Dir), with a lot of files in it. in another branch, there's no such directory at all.

When I cloned this svn repository with git svn, on master things are all right, but on the branch, I got the TOD directory and the same directory structure except there's no files in it.

If I rm the TOD directory (safe because git doesn't track directories), and switch to master and run git svn rebase, I got the "creating empty direcotry" messages, then when I checkout the branch, the TOD directory comes back.

All in all, the question is, how to prevent git svn from creating empty TOD directories on the branch?

Comment: Doesn't setting `svn-remote.<name>.automkdirs` to false and `svn.rmdir` to true help?

Comment: For anyone wondering what value should be used for <name>, this can be found by inspecting the .git/config file. There is a section labeled [svn-remote "svn"] which means that svn is the name of your remote, which is the default if you have not specified some other name for the svn-remote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe @ben-tebulin is correct, that by doing

```
git config svn-remote.svn.automkdirs false
git config svn.rmdir true
```

should make things right. Unfortunately I soon moved to other projects and didn't have a chance to verify it.

At the time of writing this, I, almost lost my svn-fu, did a test and couldn't reproduce the problem, and it looks git-svn can now switch between branches cleanly.

Comment: If you inspect the difference of the .git/config file before and after running these commands you will get a better idea of what these commands are doing. The <name> you should use for the svn-remote.<name> command is located in the section [svn-remote "<name>"] of the .git/config file. The default <name> is set to "svn", as is demonstrated in this answer.